# C# Winforms autosize GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

My problem is the following:
I have a code which gets items from an xml file. This should be parsed and tabs, groupboxes and labels should be generated accordingly.

I have the following code:

```
foreach(XmlNode function in root.SelectNodes("function"))
{
    string functionName = function.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(functionName);
    FlowLayoutPanel fLP_Layout = new FlowLayoutPanel();

    foreach(XmlNode port in function.SelectNodes("Port"))
    {
        string portName = port.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        GroupBox gB = new GroupBox();
        gB.Text = portName;

        TableLayoutPanel tLP_PortLayout = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tLP_PortLayout.Location = new Point(5, 20);
        tLP_PortLayout.ColumnCount = 2;

        var y = 20;

        foreach(XmlNode register in port.SelectNodes("Register"))
        {
            Label l_register = new Label();
            l_register.Location = new Point(5, y);
            l_register.Text = register.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
            TextBox tB_Value = new TextBox();
            tB_Value.Location = new Point(50, y - 4);

            tLP_PortLayout.Controls.Add(l_register);
            tLP_PortLayout.Controls.Add(tB_Value);
            y += 20;
        }

        gB.Controls.Add(tLP_PortLayout);
        fLP_Layout.Controls.Add(gB)
    }

    tabPage.Controls.Add(fLP_Layout);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
}
```

And well, as you can imagine it doesn't work. The groupbox always has the default size and does not resize according to the content. Neither does the TableLayoutPanel inside the groupbox.

Comment: what happens if you add this: `gB.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;` or try `gB.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` Do the same for the layout panel.

Comment: Andy, unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. My problem does not occur when changing the size of the window but when adding content to the groupbox.

Comment: You haven't set `gB.AutoSize = true;`, this property defaults to `false` (you'd need to set it even if the default was `true`).

Comment: Jimi, Well... I tried that already. But I think because of the TableLayoutPanel somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: Setting AutoSize __will__ work. Try again!

Comment: I set gB.AutoSize = true; right after gB.Text = portName; Doesn't work. Still the groupBox is that small that only 3 of 5 rows are shown because of the groupBoxes size.

Comment: You also need to set `tLP_PortLayout.AutoSize = true;`  There is no point in setting `tB_Value.Location = new Point(50, y - 4);` and `l_register.Location = new Point(5, y);` that's the whole point in using a `TableLayoutPanel` is that it takes care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks! The tLP_PortLayout.AutoSize = true solved it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

setting

```
tLP_PortLayout.AutoSize = true;
```

and

```
gB.AutoSize = true
```

solved the issue for me. Thanks @Loathing.